# Correct incantation of subprocess with shell=True to get output and not hang

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

Inside a subprocess call, I want to use *shell=True* so that it does globbing on pathnames (code below), however [this has the annoying side-effect of making *`subprocess`* spawn a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true) (which must then be *`communicate()d/ poll()ed/ wait()ed/ terminate()d/ kill()ed/ whatevah*).

(Yes I am aware the globbing can also be done with [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html)/[glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html), but please show me the 'correct' use of subprocess on this, i.e. the minimal incantation to both get the stdout and stop the child process.)

This works fine (returns output):

> *`subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/wc','-l','[A-Z]*/[A-Z]*.F*'], shell=False)`*

but this hangs

> *`subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/wc','-l','[A-Z]*/[A-Z]*.F*'], shell=True)`*

(PS: It's seriously aggravating that you can't tell subprocess you want **some** but not **all** shell functionality e.g. globbing but not spawning. I think there's a worthy PEP in that, if anyone cares to comment, i.e. pass in a tuple of Boolean, or an *or* of binary flags)

(PPS: the idiom of whether you pass *`subprocess...(cmdstring.split() or [...])`* is just a trivial idiomatic difference. I say tomato, you say tomay-to. In my case, the motivation is the command is fixed but I may want to call it more than once with a difference filespec.)

Comment: How would you tell the underlying _shell_ that you want only some but not all of its functionality? Until the underlying shell supports it (across a wide enough array of platforms), there's not much support for having an API to access it...

Comment: @Charles: I didn't say tell shell. I said ***tell subprocess***. subprocess can fake out with calls to fnmatch instead of full-blown shell, I really don't give a hoot how it achieves it. But this is doable, if painful.

Comment: I read `shell=True` to mean that I want an actual UNIX shell invoked. If you suddenly have `subprocess` *faking* being a shell, you're asking it to figure out what the Right Thing (or expected thing, at least) is on the native shell of every platform Python supports. Keep in mind that different shells support different variants on glob syntax, different forms of redirection, different flow control constructs (as those can certainly be used in one-liners started by `subprocess`)... you'd basically have to implement an actual UNIX shell in Python, and that would be insane.

Comment: The intent with `shell=True` is `"give me globbing"`. I know I get some other unwanted (and possibly insecure) behavior, that's the price shell=True forces you to pay (which as I say is in my opinion a design wart).

Comment: that may be _your_ intent in using `shell=True`, but to assume such as universal seems like a bit of a stretch -- speaking for myself, when I use `shell=True`, I want redirection and all the rest, and I wouldn't use it otherwise. A PEP proposing a standard-library call to evaluate globs in an argument list, with integration with subprocess to allow the cwd against which they're evaluated to be appropriately adjusted, _does_ seem like a good idea; painting it as an alternative to `shell=True` is the only part I find questionable.

Comment: @Charles: that's entirely my point: there are multiple separate use cases for saying `shell=True`. I am well aware that there are many other reasons for using shell than globbing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off -- there's very little point to passing an array to:

```
subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/wc','-l','A-Z*/A-Z*.F*'], shell=True)
```

...as this simply runs `wc` with no arguments, in a shell also passed arguments `-l` and `A-Z*/A-Z*.F*` as arguments (to the shell, not to `wc`). Instead, you want:

```
subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/wc -l A-Z*/A-Z*.F*', shell=True)
```

Before being corrected, this would hang because `wc` had no arguments and was reading from stdin. I would suggest ensuring that `stdin` is passed in closed, rather than passing along your Python program's `stdin` (as is the default behavior).

An easy way to do this, since you have `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.check_output(
    '/usr/bin/wc -l A-Z*/A-Z*.F* </dev/null',
    shell=True)
```

...alternately:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/wc -l A-Z*/A-Z*.F*', shell=True,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
(output, _) = p.communicate(input='')
```

...which will ensure an empty `stdin` from Python code rather than relying on the shell.

Comment: Aha! True, the files exist in some but not all of the globbed subdirectories, I take it for granted subprocess does not do insane things like spawning with no arguments. So how do I make this work without extreme pain? (and other than manually using fnmatch)? I mean, the UNIX equivalent ***just works***.

Comment: @smci no, the UNIX equivalent doesn't Just Work -- it has the exact same problem, at least if the `nullglob` shell option is true (which, admittedly, it isn't by default, for exactly this reason). Also, see my amendment.

Comment: Interesting. It still hangs with redirected `*</dev/null*` (Python 2.7.2+ on Ubuntu). Btw I never heard of *nullglob* until you just mentioned it, and it sanely defaults to false, so the UNIX command-line does indeed ***just work***.

Comment: @smci can't reproduce that. `subprocess.check_output('wc -l </dev/null', shell=True)` immediately returns `0\n`. (Also Python 2.7.2+, also on Ubuntu).

Comment: Sorry, somehow I dropped the brackets in the filespec, doh. *`subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/wc -l [A-Z]*/[A-Z]*.F* </dev/null', shell=True)`* is indeed what I wanted. Can you also show the 'correct' textbook version where you would do subp.stdin.close()?

Comment: @smci sure, I'd be glad to add that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9341/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-smci)

Comment: @smci, ...btw, while this answer was a good one, my explanation for the original problem was not (nothing to do with nullglob, everything to do with how arrays are handled with `shell=True`). I've gone back and corrected it.